# C # Winform : Sending data from sql to web service

Tags: c#, sql, oracle, weblogic

I will try to explain it as shortly as I can.
We use 'proxy' for the connection.
The web service that I can try to connect is Oracle Weblogic.I have got the username and the password.
I can connect to the web service without any problem by using the progrqm soapUI.And on the program I choose this option.Becaue I can only connect to the web service by choosing this.

Authenticate Preemptively :     Send Authentication headers with each request without first receiving an authentication challenge. This is a potential security hazard but will improve performance since only one request will be required for authenticated endpoints instead of two.

I can not connect to the web service by using C# winform.I made a lot of research but I could not find anything helpful.
Could you give me an example?

Comment: Why can't you connect to the web service via your Winform?

Comment: I dont know how to :(

Comment: There are tutorials [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scf355x6(v=vs.90).aspx), [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36237/Webservice-with-Win-Forms-and-Web-Forms) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18585536/sending-and-receiving-data-from-web-service-in-winform).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please have a look at the sample [here](http://www.csharptutorial.in/2012/01/cnet-how-to-consume-web-service-in-cnet.html#.Uo0Kq8STxrM) in connecting to a web service via C#. Or you can use a code first method. which ever suites your needs.

Happy Coding :)

Comment: I tried these examples a lot.I can not connect to web service without  choosing the option 'adds authentication information to outgoing request'. I want to add this option to the code.